# s3 bucket policy to allow iam user to upload image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I have a bucket named **prod-mysite-me** on my s3. Within the bucket I have a folder named **avatars**. And inside the avatars folder there are several email_address folders and within each the the image file resides

For clearer explanation this is the structure of the bucket

```
prod-mysite-me/
 - avatars/
  - email_address1.@domain.com
    - image1.jpg
  - email_address2@domain.com
    - image1.jpg
  so on ...
```

Now what I want is to be able to have a permission to upload on **prod-mysite-me/avatars/my_email@domain.com/my_image.jpg**. Sorry this is my first time experiencing S3 uploading.

Answer (score 0):

You need an IAM role with below mentioned policy :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::prod-mysite-me/avatars/my_email@domain.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Further read :

1. [IAM Role for S3](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/iam-roles.html)
2. [How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)